# TikZ matrix of node: How can I space rows individually?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I would like to arrange multiple nodes in a TikZ matrix, but with different horizontal spaces between each other. Say, I want node "a" and "b" to be 30 mm apart, node "b" and "c" to be 60 mm apart, and node "c" and "d" to be 5 mm apart. While a `|yshift=30mm|` command does cause an effect, I couldn't achieve anything with the corresponding `xshift` command inside the matrix.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (eineMatrix) [matrix of nodes, column sep=10mm]{
    a&b&c&d\\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `&` macro accepts an optional argument: ``a &[30mm] b &[60mm] c &[5mm] d \\``

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Thank you, works like a charm!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is solved by comment.